# Meaning of ゲロった in ぼっちルーチンをゲロっただけでした

Tags: meaning, slang

For context I have added an excerpt below.

A summary of the context is that the protagonist was called out for being a 'stalker', and he 'proves' his innocence by showing her videos that show it was just coincidence (he is a hacker so he was able to obtain access to these videos from the security cameras, and she did question where he got them from).

So on to how to understand the final sentence. ゲロる seems to be a verb used (in this context) similarly to confess/letting the cat out the bag.

So is the final sentence saying something like:
"With a smug face I called out this guy for stalking me, but all he did was confess his 'ぼっちルーチン'.

Is this the correct understanding for the below?

> 「な？　どう見てもコイツ、目の前の飯とスマホにしか興味ないだろ」
> 「たしかに……こんな退屈そうな食事風景、初めて見た」
> 「あんたも人のこと言えないと思うんだけど」
> 「うっさい！　ぼっち言うな！」
> １週間前に中庭で食べたときの映像には、隅っこにさりげなく少女の姿が映り込んでいた。ベンチのはす向かい同士で、俺と彼女はまったく同じ姿勢で黙々とパンを食べていた。
> 「毎回必ず先客がいるなーって思ってたけど……　そうか。全部、あんただったのか」
> 「ぐ……」
> 「ん、待てよ。それってつまり、あんたの行く先に俺がいたんじゃなくて――」
> 「ま、待って。それ以上は――」
> 「あんたが昼休みに毎回ぼっちスポットにいるだけなんじゃ……」
> 「やけに一人になれる場所が少ないと思ったら、まさか同志がいたとは。そりゃ領土も限られるよなぁ」
> 「うう、同類を見る目はやめろー！」
> 「サイアク……恥ずすぎる。ドヤ顔でストーカー捕まえたら、ぼっちルーチンを**ゲロった**だけでしたー、って……」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ゲロる is a slang word meaning "to confess/reveal/say (against one's will / after being persuaded, investigated or tortured)". The connotation in parentheses is important because this is not used to describe a voluntary confession like something one may do at church.

By the way, doesn't the last sentence mean "All **I** did was confess **my** ぼっちルーチン"? It appears to me that she is embarrassed not because she called the wrong person a stalker but because she had to admit her ぼっち-ness.

Source:

- https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%AD%E3%82%8B